# SFTP a HTML made on the fly file to an external sever

Tags: php, html, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to SFTP a HTML file made on the fly(using file put contents) and the shh2 library.

Here's what I've got so far, apache reports that it can't be sent as the file doesn't exist on the local disk:

```
$pageBody = '<body>
    <div id="canvas_container">
        <canvas id="designer_canvas" width="430" height="415">
        </canvas>
    </div>
<div style="display:none" id="share_design_details">
<li>'.$mc1.'</li><li>'.$mc1.'</li><li>'.$mc2.'</li><li>'.$sp.'</li><li>'.$p.'</li><li>'.$c.'</li></div>

<div id="test">This design is called : '.$designName.'</div></body>' ; 


$newFile = file_put_contents('newfile.html',$pageBody);
$connection = ssh2_connect('myhost.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'myuser', 'mypass');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
ssh2_scp_send($connection, $newFile, $newFile, 0644);
```

Comment: http://php.net/file_put_contents returns true or false, but ssh2_scp_send() requires a file path

Comment: How I do modify the send so it uploads the file without having to create it on the local disk?

Comment: I don't think you can. I'd say just pass it the file name and delete it afterwards

Comment: Cheers, I'll leave it open in case there is a way, but post it as an answer as it might be useful to others.

Comment: See Example #1 Opening a file via SFTP at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php — just open the file for writing instead of reading

Comment: Infra, you may have been down voted as your question doesn't include a clear "question" as such. You simply said what you have done so far and that it didn't work. You could have said "What PHP logic do I need to use to generate a HTML file on a remote SFTP server" and then explain further what you have so far. That's my guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ssh2_scp_send()** function requires the file path for the local and remote files.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php

The **file_put_contents()** function returns the number of bytes written to the file, not the file path.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Therefore, your **ssh2_scp_send()** should read something as follows where the target directory on your target server is */tmp*:

```
ssh2_scp_send($connection, 'newfile.html', '/tmp/newfile.html', 0644);
```

I don't think it is possible to upload a file that does not exist yet as you would essentially be writing directly to the target server as opposed to uploading a file.

I would simply delete the file after sending using the **unlink()** function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

So your complete logic would be as follows:

```
//Define content
$pageBody = 'CONTENT HERE';

//Create the file
$newFile = file_put_contents('temp.html', $pageBody);

//Connect to SFTP host
$connection = ssh2_connect('myhost.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'myuser', 'mypass');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

//Send the file
ssh2_scp_send($connection, 'temp.html', '/tmp/temp.html', 0644);

//Delete the local file
unlink('temp.html);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation, myself. eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

//Define content
$pageBody = 'CONTENT HERE';

//Connect to SFTP host
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('myhost.com', 22);
$sftp->login('myuser', 'mypass');

//Send the file
$sftp->put('/tmp/temp.html', $pageBody);
?>
```

Much more portable and arguably easier to use too.

Answer (score 0):

***Completely*** untested, but normally writing to the SSH connection (under a shell, mind you) makes it available to the other side. With that in mind, run a command that puts it in the right place on the other side and then write to it.

```
$stream = ssh_exec('cat > some/file');
$result = fwrite($stream, $pageBody);
```